# Consuming secured WCF service through basicHTTPbinding

Tags: c#-3.0, wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-security

I am consuming an secured service hosted over basicHttpBinding
I have to pass credentials to the service for authenticatioon

Here’s the config setting for the client

```
<security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
          realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
```

While calling the service, I am getting following exception message

An unsecured or incorrectly secured fault was received from the other party. See the inner FaultException for the fault code and detail.
Message = "An invalid security token was provided (Bad UsernameToken Values)”

I not sure how to get it working I am curious if somebody can help me out or provide me any url where I could find the solution

Answer (score 0):

When you create your `MyServiceClient` object you can set the username and password on the `clientInstance.Credentials.UserName` object.